# Xcode Version & Build Number and submission to iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode, versioning, app-store-connect

Hopefully this is a simple question and I'm struggling to understand how xCode & iTunes Connect use and check the xCode applications Version & Build numbers. Also I'm dealing with a legacy application that has never managed the build numbers correctly and is already available via iTunes.

What I'm trying to do is use the version number for exactly that, versioning and want to have version number as follows:

1.0.0
1.0.1
1.1.4 etc etc

The build number we increment each time we issue an internal build and is just a number similar to 102, this just increases.

My understanding so far is that when I upload a new version of the application the build number has to be greater than the previous release. But does this process take into account the version number. So....

Version : 1.0.0 Build : 100 <<<<< This is the initial iTunes release
Version : 1.0.0 Build : 101 <<<<< For this the build number must be greater than previous

Version : 1.0.1 Build : 001 <<<<< Would this work and Itunes accept it?

If this is not how it works I'm assuming there's no way to reset version & build number so they work correctly once they have been submitted to iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

What XCode shows as Build in the General tab of the target properties is in fact the Long Version String and what it shows as Version is the Short Version String.

When you submit an update to the iTunesConnect, both the Version and the build have to be greater than the previous version and build on the AppStore.

From Apple Developer site:

- Build - [CFBundleVersion in info.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102364)
- Version -
  [CFBundleShortVersionString in info.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-111349)

The Version is what shows up on the iTunes App Store and the Build is what only the developer and iTunes Connect can see.